# Выборка html элементов по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите разобраться , не могу понять в чем ошибка.. В общем задача следуюшая , нужно что бы вытягивался элемент из html по клику на нем и предположим выводилось значение этого элемента alertом.

```
window.onload=function(){
    gtClassName('B');
}


function gtClassName(nameClass){
    with(this){
        ObjectAdd = document.getElementsByClassName(nameClass);
        ObjectAdd.addEventListener('click' , outDate);
        function outDate(){
            alert(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Проделывал такое с помощью `jq`, но на чистом `js` не получается. При выборке по id работает, а по классу выдает в консоли ошибку:

> TypeError: ObjectAdd.addEventListener is not a function;

И если указать `ObjectAdd` с индексом то тоже все сработает. Подскажите как сделать так , что бы процесс не требовал обращения к циклам , иначе как можно через `this` это сделать?

Заранее cпасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решается с помощью итерации как и было сказано пользователем Mr. Brightside,
вот собственно и решение:

```
       window.onload = function(){
       var p = new getClassAndBinding();
        p.getValAndClick(Имя класса в HTML);
        }
      function getClassAndBinding(){

     this.getValAndClick = function(NameClass){

    this.getCls = document.getElementsByClassName(NameClass);
    for(i = 0;i<this.getCls.length;i++){
      this.getCls[i].addEventListener('click' , function(){
            alert(this.value);
    });}

        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, будет ошибка, ведь вам возвращается массив объектов, с заданным классом (читать доку [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)). Если вы подставите ObjectAdd[0], то событие должно срабатывать для первого элемента.

Вы можете воспользоваться чем-нибудь подобным:

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.addEventListener('click' , function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
            text = target.textContent || text.innerText; 
        alert(text);
    });
};
```

Однако, тут событие будет выводить уведомление при любом клике в любое место документа.

Согласно указанной выше документации, использование getElementsByClassName позволяет получить дочерние элементы только нужного элемента, и обрабатывать клики, соответственно, только для них. Однако, боюсь, без итерации тут не обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо, решил..

Comment: вы можете опубликовать своё решение здесь, чтобы другие участники, столкнувшись с такой же задачей, могли воспользоваться вашим решением.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, лучше сказать не массив, а коллекция